# User input to determine if main function restarts or ends

Tags: c, input, label, do-while

I'm working on a small project right now that allows a user to choose an array editing function from a switch statement. Unfortunately, I coded it poorly (I can't make the switch menu its own function at this point, it is part of main().) I only bring this up to prevent suggestions involving calling a menu function. I also cannot use main() recursion because I take user input for the array and do not want to replace the existing values.

The code below is supposed to take user input to decide whether to exit the program or to re-open the selection screen and

```
char restart = 'y';
    
      do {
    
        printf("Would you like to try a different function? (Y/N): ");
        restart = getchar();
        restart = getchar();
    
        system("clear");
        goto START; // "START" is the label for my main selection screen function.
        
      } while ( restart == 'Y' || restart == 'y');
      
      system("clear");
      printf("Okay, thank you!\n\n");
      
      for (i = 3; i > 0; i++) {
        printf("Exiting in %d seconds...", &i);
        sleep(1);
      }
```

(At the end of main() I included an exit function.)

I have two questions:

1. How can I detect if the user inputs an invalid character? (Not n, N, y, Y) I was initially going to build this with if-else statements, but realized that was ineffective. However, now I no longer know how to work with the do-while loop to detect these inputs.
2. This code simply doesn't work. What'd I do wrong? When inputting y or Y, the loop never exits. Should I embed the do-while loop in a while loop utilizing breaks?

My only theories right now (as a baby C programmer) are that labels don't work with this method or that I have no real way to break from the loop.

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling `getchar` twice. Then first call will return the user's response, and the second call will likely return the newline character, so `restart` will likely be a newline character. But that doesn't even matter, because the `goto` is unconditional, so the code **will** go to `START` no matter what the user enters.

Comment: If you really want help with this, you need to post a **complete** set of compilable code. But that code also has to be **minimal**. For example, if your `switch` statement has 100, cases, you should remove at least 98 of them. See [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @user3386109. The only reason I used getchar twice is because it wouldn't even let me input if I used one, it would just take a newline as the input. Is there a workaround? getchar seems to be really fussy.

Comment: All the C input routines are really fussy, and need to be handled with care. If you expected the first `getchar` to read a newline, it's because you did something incompletely before getting to this point in the code.

Comment: One thing you need to realize is that you should never mix C input routines. If you use `scanf` anywhere, use `scanf` everywhere. If you use `getchar` anywhere, then use `getchar` everywhere. If you feel like neither of those works for everything you want to do, then using `fgets` to read a line at a time is probably a good starting point. But it's hard to give you specific advice without seeing the whole picture, which is why a [mcve] is so important.